# monitor which process modified a file under FreeBSD/Linux

Tags: linux, freebsd, system

From time to time, a file that I'm interested in is modified by some process.  I need to find out which process is modifying this file.  Using lsof will not work, nor does kqueue.  Is this possible under FreeBSD and Linux?

Comment: This sounds like a sysadmin question as oppose to a programmer's question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, there's a kernel patch floating around for [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). However, some have said this is rarely useful and that it can be a security risk. In any case, here's the [patch](http://lwn.net/Articles/307536/).

Apart from that, I'm not sure there's any way to get the PID, either with *inotify* or *dnotify*. You could investigate further (e.g. search for *pid dnotify* or *pid inotify*), but I believe it isn't likely.

Answer (score 1):

On FreeBSD, perhaps it should be best if you [check its auditing features](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/audit-config.html).

Answer (score 1):

Linux has an audit daemon http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html

See also [auditd homepage](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/)

Answer (score 0):

You can see which processes opened a file just installing and using lsof (LiSt Open Files) command.